# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined node-carto

Tags: node.js, openstreetmap

I am creating an OpenStreetMap tile server on Ubuntu 18.04 and am having issues with carto.

It installed just fine, but when it came to building the Mapnik xml stylesheet (`carto project.mml > style.xml`), I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined.

I have looked all over for an answer and there is no definite one. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am following this tutorial: [OpenStreetMap Tile Server on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-16-04)

**I am aware this tutorial follows Ubuntu 16.04**

Comment: Offtopic for StackOverflow. Try help.openstreetmap.org or http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

i had the same proplem after some search i found this [artikel](https://lifearoundkaur.wordpress.com/2016/02/16/osm-continued/)

so i run the folowing commands line:

- dpkg -i –force-overwrite
  nodejs-legacy_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_all.deb(dosent work for me)
- apt-get -f install
- apt-get purge nodejs-legacy nodejs
- apt-get install nodejs
- npm install millstone carto
- npm install -g carto

and it worked like charm