# Carto raises TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, ubuntu-20.04, mapnik

I have been following this tutorial:
https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-20-04-lts/

and got stuck on running

```
carto project.mml > mapnik.xml
```

My goal is to set OSM server - so expected behaviour of carto is compiling project.mml into "ready-to-render" mapnik.xml.

Actual behaviour is like the following:
Carto raises error:

```
ubuadmin@klab-osm:~/src/openstreetmap-carto$ carto -v
/usr/lib/nodejs/carto/lib/carto/tree/reference.js:19
    if (mapnik_reference.version.hasOwnProperty(version)) {
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at Object.ref.setVersion (/usr/lib/nodejs/carto/lib/carto/tree/reference.js:19:34)
    at /usr/lib/nodejs/carto/lib/carto/tree/reference.js:209:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/carto/lib/carto/tree/reference.js:213:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

I am aware of this Github Issue:
https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/issues/3409
and this SO question:
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined node-carto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288524/typeerror-cannot-read-property-hasownproperty-of-undefined-node-carto)
but haven't found them helpful.

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa, mapnik version is 0.1, I am unable to check carto version due to error mentioned above.

Trick is, because of company policy the machine I am working on is not (and won't be) connected to the Internet - I log in via SSH. Because of that I installed carto using `sudo apt install nodejs-carto` insted of `npm install -g carto` - the company has mirror on Ubuntu repository inside intranet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently, the problem was carto version being too low - after updating to `carto@1.2.0` the issue disappeared.